# NodeJS Callback not a function Async waterfall

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async.js

I've been writing a simple server, and have come across an issue where I get a callback undefined error, despite having a callback parameter in my function header. Every example I've seen on Google has been people not having a callback parameter, but I seem to have one? The error that is thrown is TypeError: callback is not a function.

Code:

```
app.post("/api/info/", function(req, res){
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            debugger;
            jwt.verify(req.body.jwt, secret.secret, {ignoreExpiration: false}, 
            function(err, decoded){
                console.log(err);
                console.log(decoded.uuid);
                debugger;
                if(err) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log("error1: " + err);
                    debugger;
                    res.json({
                        status: 403
                    });
                    res.end();
                    callback("JWT auth failed", null);
                    return;
                }
                debugger;
                callback(null, decoded.uuid);
            });
        },
        function(err, token, callback){ //query db for user uuid


       debugger;
        pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR (uuid," + "'" + token + "') > 0", function(err, rows){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            debugger;
            callback(rows); //where it errors
        });
    },
    function(rows, callback){ //get user's school name
    debugger;
        var schoolId = rows[0].chapter_uuid;
        pool.query("SELECT * FROM chapters WHERE INSTR (uuid," + "'" + schoolId + "') > 0", function(err, result){
            debugger;
            callback(rows, result[0].school);
        });
    }, 
    function(rows, chapter, callback){ //return db results to user in json
        debugger;
        var canMakeEvent = 0;
        if(rows[0].is_board){
            canMakeEvent = 1;
        }
        var info = {
            firstName: rows[0].first_name,
            lastName: rows[0].last_name,
            email: rows[0].email,
            chapter: chapter,
            isBoard: canMakeEvent,
            boardPosition: rows[0].board_position
        };
        res.json({
            status: 200,
            info: info
        });
        res.end();
        debugger;
        callback(null);
    }
], function(err){console.log(err);});
});
```

Comment: Okay, *where* do you get the error?

Comment: There's a comment in the code, right below "SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR". Header of the async function is function(err, token, callback). Sorry if the code is hard to read, stackoverflow screwed up the tabbing/spacing.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked that.  The problem is not obvious to me yet.  Have you looked to see what callback is, whether it's defined?  Is everything (such as the JWT validation) working as expected?  I ask, because calling `res.end();` *followed by* `callback("JWT auth failed",...` strikes me as unusual though perhaps not necessarily incorrect.

Comment: Console logging the body of the JWT returns what's supposed to be in the JWT. Callback SHOULD be defined, but console logging it gives undefined, even though callback is in the method header of the function that errors. I don't see how it's possible that callback doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
   function(err, token, callback){ //query db for user uuid


   debugger;
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR (uuid," + "'" + token + "')  > 0", function(err, rows){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        debugger;
        callback(null,rows); //where it errors
    });
},
```

The inner function in `pool.query` takes 2 parameters: `err` and `rows`. So in the returning `callback`, it requires 2 parameters. Since 1st parameter is `err`, in `callback` use `null` since it need to be called only `if(!err)` condition is satisfied.